# Can't create items in context menu in WPF editor

Tags: c#, wpf

I've made a context menu in WPF for my TabItem. But for some reason, it won't allow me to add items to it. I was hoping to pop up a box with options like, close, rename, etc. I've got the Items collection, just everything's greyed out. I'm quite new to WPF and C# so feel free to point out the obvious. I'm in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Can you post the relevant bits of the code you have.

Comment: What code? It's in the WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: I thought you were talking about adding items programmatically at runtime, rather than in the designer.

Comment: Nah, programmatically at runtime was easy. The designer just won't do it for some reason. Inserting into the XAML manually worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inserted stuff manually into the XAML and it accepted it without problems. Not funny, but not a big deal.